# Can we allocate memory for char * but return it as const char *?

Tags: c, casting, return-type

Is it correct to return `const char *` from a function when the actual buffer being returned is not a constant array?

For example, in this minimal example below, `buffer` is a non-const `char *` but then it is returned as `const char *`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *str_alloc(const char *str, size_t n)
{
    char *buffer;
    if ((buffer = malloc(n)) != NULL) {
        memcpy(buffer, str, n);
    }
    return buffer;
}

int main()
{
    const char *str = str_alloc("hello", 6);

    if (str == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("str: %s\n", str);

    // str[0] = 'H'; // error: read-only variable is not assignable

    free((void *) str);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, returning a non-const `char *buffer` as `const char *` helps me to enforce that the caller cannot modify the content of the buffer without an explicit type cast. But I would like to know if this is well-defined code or if this code invokes undefined behaviour due to treating `char *` as `const char *`?

Comment: It’s well-defined to return it as a `const char*`, but I wouldn’t do it anyway, because you have to cast the const away to free it.

Comment: Unrelated: if malloc returns NULL, then `str_alloc` returns an inderminate value. And `free((void *) str)`  can safely be replaced  with `free(str)`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for noticing that and pointing it out. Fixed the code in question to perform a `NULL` check on the return value of `str_alloc()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is well defined code since you restrict the usage possibility of the value. As the saying goes "who can do more, can do less". The opposit would not be valid and would require an explicit cast.

But there is a problem with your code. Passing the size of the string as argument is unsafe. In your example, you won’t copy the '\0' in the allocated buffer. As a consequence, the string is not properly terminated. The behavior of your program is undefined and could end in a segmentation fault because the `printf` would try to access data beyond the end of the buffer.

It would be preferable that the length of the string is determined in the `str_alloc` function.

Comment: Can you elaborate why my code won't copy `'\0'` in the allocated buffer. `"hello\0"` has 6 bytes including the terminating null character and I am asking `memcpy()` to copy 6 bytes, so it should copy the terminating null character too, should it not? What am I missing?

Comment: @LoneLearner oops sorry, you are right, hello is only 5 characters long. I was too quick to answer. But this error proves my point. It’s easy to make a mistake in the effective string length and the given value. It is better to compute the length by using strlen

Comment: Point taken. I agree, it is definitely safer to compute the length using `strlen()` within `str_alloc()` and use that length plus 1 to allocate memory for the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's well defined.

Supporting this is why C lets you freely convert pointers to less qualified types to pointers to more qualified types.

Converting back to a pointer to a less qualified type (in this case `char const*` => `char *`) is also possible, but requires an explicit cast, because the resulting pointer to a less qualified type (in this case `char *`) may only be used for defined dereferencing iff the effective type of the target isn't more qualified than the pointer target ([6.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7)).

In your case, the user of the `char const*` may cast it back to `char *` and then dereference, because the memory is effectively non-`const`, but if you returned a `char const*` pointer derived from e.g., a `static char const x[] = "foo";`, then casting to `char *` and dereferencing would lead to undefined behavior, because the target's effective type is more qualified than `char`.